# semi colon delimited xs:attribute xsd

Tags: attributes, xsd

I'm currently building an XSD to validate some XML I'm working on, I'm guessing this probably isn't possible but I'm wondering if there is some way to enforce an attribute that is a ";" delimited list for example

```
<nbsp style="cell-width:1.29;background-color:#99CC00;"/>
```

similar to the way the style attribute works in html.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a type which must match a specific [pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-pattern).

Example:

```
<simpleType name='better-us-zipcode'>
  <restriction base='string'>
    <pattern value='[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?'/>
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this but this intention is to get some context help if possible

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to validate the content.

```
<xs:attribute name="code">

<xs:simpleType>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[A-Z][A-Z]"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

</xs:attribute>
```

see also

http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_attribute.asp
and
  http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_simple_attributes.asp
and
  http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp

test your regexp here:  http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx